# Heroku crash after 90 sec working java telegram bot

Tags: java, maven, heroku, telegram-bot

I wrote java Telegram bot using this api - https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots . I test it on my PC and it works good. So I decided to test it on Heroku, how ever, after 90sec working it crash (first 90 sec works well). Heroku log:

```
2018-07-09T08:01:45.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2018-07-09T08:01:46.940201+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=18914 -jar target/AllaBot-1.0.0.jar`
2018-07-09T08:01:49.163121+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
2018-07-09T08:01:49.166682+00:00 app[web.1]: Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx300m -Xss512k -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2018-07-09T08:03:17.028453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2018-07-09T08:03:17.028604+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-07-09T08:03:17.121323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-07-09T08:03:17.140915+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

my Procfile:

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/AllaBot-1.0.0.jar
```

As I understand, I need to change port in my project, don't me? I try to use some tips from internet but they don't works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch

The error tells us that you need to listen to the port that the heroku will give us. So let's do it

```
    public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    private static final String TOKEN = System.getenv("TOKEN");
    private static final String BOT_USERNAME = System.getenv("BOT_USERNAME");
    private static final String PORT = System.getenv("PORT");

    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {

    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return BOT_USERNAME;
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return TOKEN;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi api = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            api.registerBot(new Bot());
        } catch (TelegramApiRequestException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.valueOf(PORT))) {
            while (true) {
                Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sergey Nik's answer helped me a lot after wasting plenty of time on attempts to fix this R10 error. I can append that Procfile should be placed in a root directory and can look like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -Dserver.port=$PORT -jar target/<custom-bot>.jar
```